# Advanced automated text editors than awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

Is there anything ahead of awk or sed? For example, something with visual edit or preview IDE? :)

Comment: which os? - what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [Sed & Awk GUI editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sedawkguieditor/) what you're looking for?